# view results not show for unadministrator users

Tags: views, users

There is a views that it `access` set to `permission:view published contents` ,every thing seems ok but I meet strange things, The views result not show for non-administrator user,
first I think the views result node are unpublished but they are not ,another idea was check the permission `view published contents` but It check for all `roles`.
**any idea about where is the problem and how can I solve it ?**
    thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your view path or URL? Is this URL protected for any specific user role?

1) Is there any field permission is given?

2) Can you please select `role` instead of `permission` from `access`? And set specific role you want to give permission.

3) Is there any contextual filter is applied?

4) Check your views filter criteria. Remove some of the filters which you have doubt on that filter and try it.

Comment: tnx for your atention and reply, I check all of them, the problem where in relationship, relation to a product that not have desired permission,I work in this site as debugger and I dont crate it.tnx

Comment: Welcome zhilevan :)

Answer (score 0):

to solve / workaround the issue, remove the relationship, and the non-admin user gets the results when they use the exposed filters.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2366541